# Find a point that is perpendicular to line

Tags: geometry, angle

I have two directional points. Point A going to point B. Each point has an X and Y coordinate.

What I am trying to do is find a point C, with distance d.
The two constraints are that C has to be perpendicular to where B ends AND BC is always 90 degrees anti-clockwise relative to AB.

Essentially what I am asking is what are the steps to solve for C using those two constraints.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: Is AB always vertical, that is in the +/- Y direction?

Comment: @WeatherVane nope, It can go any direction

Comment: What are “directional points,” and how do they differ from vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$,$B$ are represented as complex numbers $a,b$, then $C$ is represented by the complex number $c$, where $c$ is given by
$$c=b+(di)\frac{b-a}{|b-a|}$$

Comment: does this take into consideration the only left constraint?

Comment: Yes, it turns $90^\circ$ counterclockwise (hence left). To go right, replace $i$ by $−i$. Try it with a few test cases.

Comment: Strangely enough it is not giving me the answer i want. Any way to chat with you?

Comment: Can you give me coordinates for an example (i.e., $A=(?,?),\;B=(?,?)$)

Comment: Yes I will. By the way, i think i used the wrong terminology. Instead of "left" i will use the following: BC is always 90 degrees anti-clockwise relative to AB

Comment: $90^\circ$counterclockwise turn and "left turn" mean the same thing.

Comment: Some people were telling me to use "correct" terminology. Wanted to make sure we didnt get confused. Here are the coordinates

Comment: Ax = -81.463396, Ay = 28.584223. Bx = -81.463686, By = 28.584231

Comment: For your example, what is the value of $d$?

Comment: the value of d is .0002

Comment: Using the formula in my answer, I get
$$c=-81.46369152 + (28.58403108)i$$

Comment: Strange. That is definitely a viable answer. Let me recheck a few steps i did

Comment: Note: My original formula was missing the denominator $|b-a|$. Make sure you're using the corrected formula. Also note: $|b-a|$ is complex absolute value (same as the distance between the points $A,B$).

Comment: Quasi, could you input these two values? Almost identical
Ay 28.584224, Ax -81.463396
By 28.584231, Bx -81.463686

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71614/discussion-between-kelsey-abreu-and-quasi).

Answer (score 1):

<sup>The current answer may be mathematically elegant, but for the people who like to think geometrically:</sup>

You have the points $A$ and $B$. The "line from $A$ to $B$" is given as the vector $S$, which is just the difference of the points:

$$S = B - A$$

Divide this vector by its length, to obtain a unit vector, and then scale this unit vector with with $d$, to obtain the vector $T$ with the desired length:

$$T = \frac{S}{|S|} \cdot d$$

Then rotate this vector by 90 degrees counterclockwise, to obtain vector $U$, which is the "line from $B$ to $C$":

$$U = (-T_y, T_x)$$

Finally, add this vector to point $B$ to obtain the result:

$$C = B + U$$